# How do I use pwm-beeper module in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, device-tree, pwm

I have set my PWM driven beeper up as per the Linux device tree [documentation](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/input/pwm-beeper.txt). I see that this results in an extra input device in /sys/class/input:

```
root:/sys/class/input/input0# ls
capabilities  device        event0        id            modalias      name          phys          power         properties    subsystem     uevent        uniq
root:/sys/class/input/input0# cat name
pwm-beeper
```

However, I don't see anything related to the duty cycle, polarity etc to actually control the beeper. Perhaps I am very mistaken about *pwm-beeper* as it is clearly created as an *input* device. Please help!

**[update]**

Changes in my `dts`:

```
pwm15: dmtimer-pwm@15 {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            compatible = "ti,omap-dmtimer-pwm";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
            ti,timers = <&timer15>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            #pwm-cells = <3>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
};       
beeper: pwm-beeper {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                compatible = "pwm-beeper";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                pwms = <&pwm15 0 5000>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                volume-levels = <0 8 20 40 500>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                default-volume-level = <4>;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
};
```

Relevant `dmesg`:

> [    6.716560] OF: /pwm-beeper: arguments longer than property
>   [    6.716566] of_pwm_get(): can't parse "pwms" property
>   [    6.716574] pwm-beeper pwm-beeper: Failed to request PWM device:
>   -22
>   [    6.716590] pwm-beeper: probe of pwm-beeper failed with error -22

I am utterly confused because there is just so little info about this device driver mainlined in Linux!

Answer (score 0):

can you post snippet of DT block you have added?
 try this block

```
pwm-beeper {
    compatible = "pwm-beeper";
    pwms = <&pwm4 0 5000>;
    volume-levels = <0 8 20 40 500>;
    default-volume-level = <4>;
};
```

## Update 1

TLDR; either reduce you #pwm-cells to 2
Or add one more field i.e. third field to list 
like
     pwms = <&pwm4 0 5000 1>;

```
phandle1: node1 {
     #list-cells = <2>;
}   

phandle2: node2 {
     #list-cells = <1>;
}

node3 {
     list = <&phandle1 1 2 &phandle2 3>;
}
```

here notice list has #list-cells differant

phadle1 has 2

phadle2 has 1

so accordingly list has entries.

This will work
 whats you linux version ? can you test it on latest stable ?

Comment: It is on 4.14.54. Not the latest, but pretty up to date. I just tried it and put the details in my post!

Comment: 6.716560] OF: /pwm-beeper: arguments longer than property
[ 6.716566] of_pwm_get(): can't parse "pwms" property suggestes that pwms has more arguments than expected. can you please try removing 0 and 5000 from pwms.

Comment: can you also provide entries for pwm15 ?

Comment: `pwm15` added above. Let me try removing 0 / 5000.

Comment: Strangely, I am still getting the same "more arguments than expected" error with those two values removed.

Comment: &pwm3 {
 pinctrl-names = "default";
 pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_pwm3_2>;
 status = "okay";
};
beeper {
  compatible = "pwm-beeper";
  pwms = <&pwm3 0 5000000>;
 };
from file arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qdl-qmx6.dtsi can you please give this a try

Comment: hi Adam I have gone through code it. FYI root cause                                                                             drivers/of/base.c:of_parse_phandle_with_args  returns -EINVAL
drivers/pwm/core.c:of_pwm_get -> of_parse_phandle_with_args
drivers/pwm/core.c:pwm_get -> of_pwm_get
drivers/pwm/core.c:devm_pwm_get -> pwm_get
drivers/input/misc/pwm-beeper.c:pwm_beeper_probe -> devm_pwm_get